# "Правая, она вкуснее." Правильно ли поставлена запятая?

Tags: запятые

Правильно ли поставлена запятая в предложении: "Правая, она вкуснее"?

Comment: Если вам дан (или будет дан) исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 3):

Контекста нет, поэтому понимание может быть разным.

**Ответ 1. Ответ на вопрос**

Например:  *Какая лучше? ― **Правая, она вкуснее.***

Предложение неполное (ответ на вопрос). Это БСП (бессоюзное сложное предложение). Вторая часть предложения обозначает причину (в этом случае ставится двоеточие или тире), но причинно-следственные отношения в разговорном варианте и неполном предложении  интонационно не обозначены, поэтому стоит запятая.

**Ответ 2. Именительный темы.**

Например: *Я люблю собирать первую землянику. **Первая, она вкуснее.***

**Именительный темы ― это стилистический оборот** (фигура речи), позволяющий выделить нужное слово, сделав его именительным темы. Слово в этом случае имеет логическое ударение, и во второй части делается его повтор с заменой местоимением.

В приведенном примере достаточно поставить **запятую**, но в общем случае ставится **запятая или тире**. Можно посмотреть примеры из Нацкорпуса для слова "любовь".

**Любовь, она** тоже свои законы имеет. **Любовь, она** есть, но рядом всегда есть боль и страдания.

**Любовь ― она** слепа. **Любовь — она** же по-разному себя проявляет.

Answer (score 3):

**Правая, она вкуснее.**

Запятая нужна, но смысл фразы и, соответственно, объяснение этой запятой зависит от контекста. Возможно, это ответ на вопрос "какая?". Тогда см. ответ Ксении.

Но по-моему, здесь просто утверждается, что правая вкуснее. Тогда это именительный темы. Вот полезная информация об этом для желаюших углубить свои знания:

> [>Вопрос № 296634](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=296634)
>   Добрый день! Помогите, пожалуйста, расставить знаки препинания и разобрать предложение по составу: Аня она девушка непостоянная.
>   Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>   Подлежащее – она, сказуемое – девушка непостоянная. Существительное Аня – именительный темы (именительный представления). Эта синтаксическая структура может быть оформлена по-разному. Вот, что об этом сообщают «Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник» (под ред. В. В. Лопатина. М., 2016).
>
> § 23. Именительный падеж (именительный темы или представления) как синтаксическая структура, стоящая перед предложением, тему которого она представляет, отделяется знаками препинания, соответствующими концу предложения, – точкой, восклицательным знаком, вопросительным знаком, многоточием. Каждый знак вносит соответствующий смысловой и эмоциональный оттенок: Москва, Сибирь. Два эти слова звучали именем страны (Тв.); Слово! Язык! Об этом нужно писать не короткие статьи, а страстные воззвания к писателям (Пауст.); А наши шахты? Какая-нибудь Англия, что она в угольной промышленности понимает? (Фад.); Журавли... Заваленный работою – вдалеке от сумрачных полей, я живу со странною заботою – увидать бы в небе журавлей (Сол.); Холодные и дикие просторы!.. Как давно были сказаны впервые эти слова и были ли они сказаны кем-то?.. (Расп.).
>
> Наиболее употребительны многоточие (подчеркивает момент раздумья, паузу) и восклицательный знак (экспрессивность) или сочетание восклицательного знака и многоточия.
>
> Однако при именительном темы, более тесно связанном с основным предложением, в котором имеется личное или указательное местоимение в качестве слова-отсылки, ставится тире: Тягач – он как танк, только без башни (газ.); Марченко – тот был человек, золотой человек (Каз.); Дорога в дождь – она не сладость, дорога в дождь – она беда (Евт.).
>
> Примечание. Допустимо используемое в практике печати и написание с запятой: Врач, он ведь тоже не Бог (Бык.); Судьбы человеческие, они – каждая сама по себе, хотя мы вроде бы сообща и всё у нас должно быть общим (Аст.); Наташа, та знала, что за человек ее тетя (Бит.).
>
> § 24. После именительного темы, сопровождаемого вопросительным предложением, ставится точка: Научный потенциал. Как им распорядиться? (газ.); Гастроли в Москве. Что они значат? (газ.); Разум на других планетах. Каков он? (журн.).
>
> Примечание. Допустимо используемое в практике печати и написание со знаком двоеточие: Студенческий быт: каким ему быть? (газ.).
>
> Если после именительного темы стоит вопросительная часть конструкции, которая также представляет собой форму именительного падежа, то ставится тире: Сценарий – произведение или полуфабрикат? (газ.); «Зеленая революция» – легенда или реальность? (газ.). В таких случаях возможна подстановка слова это. Ср.: Парапсихология – это трюк или реальность? Действительность или фикция? (газ.).
>
> Примечание 1. Допустимо используемое в практике печати и написание со знаком двоеточие перед вопросительной конструкцией. Например: Стадион: «цех здоровья» или футбольная арена? (газ.); Литературное произведение: символ или модель? (газ.).
>
> Примечание 2. Данные структуры с именительным темы отличаются от двусоставных предложений с подлежащим и сказуемым в именительном падеже интонацией: интонация именительного темы схожа с интонацией конца предложения (понижение тона и пауза), тогда как подлежащее в двусоставном предложении не фиксирует конечной паузы. Ср.: Стадион – цех здоровья (подлежащее и сказуемое). Здесь подлежащее и сказуемое связаны воедино интонацией утверждения.

Answer (score 2):

Есть такой антипример «Антипримерах русского языка»: *«Подлежащее, оно не нуждается в уточнении местоимением».* Это как раз ваш случай, запятая нужна.

Источник: «Правила русского языка (с антипримерами)». http://gramma.ru/RST/?id=3.575

Comment: Вы ратуете в одном из ответов за актуальность употребления тех или иных конструкций в живой речи как признак допустимости. Вполне употребляемая структура, имеющая большую литературу (см. даже упоминание в ПАС). А тут какие-то антиправила...

Comment: Если что, это юмор. И "антиправила" там разные. Есть такие, которым следовать никогда нельзя, а есть и такие (их не много), которым иногда следовать можно. Вот этому -- иногда можно.

Comment: А, то есть вы просто показали, что есть запятая, но ничего не имеете против этого предложения?

Comment: Да, ничего против не имею.